# How can I build nuxt+vue routers without 404 error?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

### Purpose

I am learning about vue.js and good practices to build websites using it, and I think that [site](https://VueVixens.org) is awesome doing things like it do (in some parts is just the way that vue does things, it amazes me). I found that open code software and I am trying to build a development environmental and modify the software itself (the license say "You can modify").

### My Environmental

OS: Debian 9

NPM: 6.4.1

node: 10.13.0

### Create the issue

```
git clone https://github.com/VueVixens/website 
cd website
npm install
npm run dev
```

### Issue

I can build and run server, but I can't access routes. When I tried to access "/", "/Sponsors", "/Library", "/Gallery", "/Team" and "/About" that error happens.
[image: terminal output]
[image: browser response]

When I tried to access "/Request" and "/Credit" that error happens.
[image: another image]

I think it's happening because nuxt can't build routers correctly, i can't figure out why!

Comment: I just ran those exact commands and it's working fine for me on Windows 10 in cmd, npm version 6.4.1 and node version 8.11.1

Comment: I change my OS to windows and built a environmental as your. Thanks to help.

Comment: the routers don`t work because a api request(on storyblok) done to get content to feed pages. The access token was changed to me, i finnaly figure out why the router issue is happening. Thanks for the help.